# What FAA or other regulations apply to autonomous quadcopters?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am a software engineer and hobby roboticist and I have just successfully built a [quadcopter drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadcopter) with a full-fledged microcontroller (running firmware that I wrote myself) inside of it, that flies around my backyard, identifies certain things that it finds and sends me reports of what it finds. I do not need to control it with any sort of remote at all.

What legal issues with the FAA and other aviation regulators might I face in trying to bring this to market as a consumer product? Never mind the electronics testing/certification/verification aspect (i.e. all the processes and hoops you have to jump through to have an official "*UL*" logo on your product). I'm wondering where modern US (likely FAA) drone law stands on completely autonomous, unmanned, non-remote-controlled quadcopter operations for commercial use -- **not** for delivering the mail like what Amazon is doing; this is just something that flies around on its own in your backyard or in a field, does simple object identification and knows how to steer clear of most obstacles.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you don't get a good response here you might also try asking on [drones.SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well, if the recent NPRM is enacted into regulation, as it likely will be, your system will soon be illegal for sale in the US unless it has a "Remote Identification" system built into it. You need to research Remote ID.  One possible starting point -- https://www.rcgroups.com/model-aircraft-and-drone-advocacy-943/